# Excel Macro that will find duplicates in each column separately

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I have a spreadsheet that has data in Columns C thru P.
Each column will have the data points that are the same.  I want to write a macro that will highlight a duplicate value in a column.

```
EX: 
Col C    Col D    Col E
Brad     Brad     Brad
Ted      Ted      Mike
Brad     Mike     Ted
Mike     Phil     Mike
```

I would like the Macro to highlight Brad in Col C nothing in col D and Mike in Col E
As a note the data from col C will be copied and pasted across Col D thru P

I have tried conditional formatting and it would only work until I copied and pasted cells.

I tried this code and it worked for only Col C I was unable to figure out how to expand it to work for each col.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Target.Row = 2 Then Exit Sub
    
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim xRng1 As Range
    Dim xRng2 As Range
    
    Set xRng1 = Range("C14:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    For Each xRng2 In xRng1
        xRng2.Offset(0, 0).Font.Color = vbBlack
        
        If Application.Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & xRng1.Address & "," & xRng2.Address & ")") > 1 Then
            xRng2.Offset(0, 0).Font.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next xRng2
    
    Set xRng1 = Nothing
    
    ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Conditional formatting should also work - something on the lines of =COUNTIF(C:C,C1)>1 although it would need adjusting if you wanted to ignore the first 13 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the `Worksheet_Change` event to find which cell was triggered, all you need to modify is the way you set-up your `xRng1` object to `Target`.

**Modified Code**

```
Option Explicit
  
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim xRng1 As Range, xRng2 As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    If Target.Row = 2 Then Exit Sub
    
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Target.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    ' set-up range object using the Column that was triggered 
    Set xRng1 = Range(Cells(14, Target.Column), Cells(LastRow, Target.Column))
    
    For Each xRng2 In xRng1
        xRng2.Offset(0, 0).Font.Color = vbBlack
        
        If Application.Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & xRng1.Address & "," & xRng2.Address & ")") > 1 Then
            xRng2.Offset(0, 0).Font.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next xRng2
    
    Set xRng1 = Nothing
    
ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much works perfect!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @lawsonsh you're welcome, Now comes your part by accepting this as an answer (by clicking on the checkmark on the left side of my answer)

Comment: Since you were able to help with that so quickly I was wondering if you could also help me adapt this code on more time.

Comment: Since you were able to help with that so quickly I was wondering if you could also help me adapt this code on more time.  On A different workbook I would like to use this code to look for entries in col B-F.  If the entry is there high light the cell in a certain color.  For EX if "RDO" is entered high light that  cell a color.  If "1" is entered high light the cell a different color.  Words it would be looking for would be any text containing the following (Duty,RDO,OFF,TR,1).

Comment: @lawsonsh can you post a new question on SO and send me the link ? I will gladly have a look at it